# javascript concatinate href

Tags: javascript, href

I am having trouble creating an href based on an array. 
Here is what I have:

```
document.write('<a href="monthName[thisMonth].htm">'+monthName[thisMonth]+'</a>');
```

I need the monthName[thisMonth].htm to be based off an array monthName, with the position of thisMonth.
The title element is working fine, but somehting is wrong with the link element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need any additional escaping, you can just do:

```
document.write('<a href="' + monthName[thisMonth] + '.htm">'+monthName[thisMonth]+'</a>');
```

Comment: Thank you my good coder, this works very well. I will break this down to understand the proper placement of the elements. I will also select this as correct answer in 10 min.